# How to remove an item from a list of entities programmatically?

Tags: razor, dotnetnuke, 2sxc

DNN 9.10.1.0 / 2sxc 11.22.01

We're using 2sxc Content and C# Razor templates.

There are 2 content types, a "parent" and a "child" one. The parent has some general fields and a list of entities of type "child".

If we want to delete one of the child entities programmatically, this doesn't work because the child entity is still in this parent/child relation with the parent entity.

The workaround so far is to update the parent entity with all the child EntityId's except that one that should be deleted. Afterwards, the now not related child entity can be deleted.

Is there a nicer way to remove an entity item which is in a list of another entity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment this is the only way to do it with public APIs.
The internal APIs can always change, so you shouldn't use them.

If you believe this is a common need, do post an issue on github and we'll consider it.